# Issue with External CSS Not Working in Dynamic Route with Express

Tags: css, node.js, ejs, dynamic-routing

I'm encountering an issue in my Express application where external CSS isn't functioning as expected when used with a specific dynamic route. Here's a summary of the situation:

When I use the dynamic route app.get("/:id", (req, res) => {...}, the external CSS styling works perfectly fine. This route structure uses only one parameter in the URL.

However, when I use the dynamic route app.get("/name/:id", (req, res) => {...}, the external CSS styling doesn't seem to be applied correctly. This route structure also uses a single parameter in the URL, but the CSS doesn't work as intended.

Notably, inline CSS and internal CSS continue to work normally regardless of the route structure.